# What counts as 'qualified government orders'?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, first-time-home-buyer, repayment

In 2008, we received a first time home buyer credit.  In 2010, I became a government employee.  In 2015, I transferred to a new position in a new city which made me part of the intelligence community.  We sold the house, so we're trying to find out if we're exempt from repayment of the remainder of the credit.  According to the form 5405 instructions:

"... Sold the home or the home ceased to be your main home after 2008 because you (or your side, if married) received Government orders to serve on qualified official extended duty..."

"You are on qualified official extended duty while:

*Serving at a duty station that is at least 50 miles from your main home..."

So my duty station is in a new city, which is more than 50 miles from my old home.  The question is if I'm considered to be here on government orders.

Comment: Did you choose to transfer to a new position?  Or were you ordered to do so?

Comment: I chose to transfer.